# Is the default case necessary

Tags: java, coding-style, switch-statement

I have a statement that goes like this:

```
public $type function_name($enum e){
if(e != null)
switch(e){
case A: return x1;
case B: return x2;
case C: return x3;
//default: do some operations
}
// default or e = null
do the exact same operations
}
```

My question is: given that the default case is treated in the rest of the method, is it necessary (in terms of good coding style) to add it to the switch statement (basically, duplicate the code for "if anything else happens" - in this case, default for switch, e = null, etc.)?

Comment: Duplicate code which makes nothing better is always bad

Answer (score 0):

Default case is not necessary in Switch-Case, but it is a good habit to use it and define a default case if non of the cases you have defined occur. If you're duplicating your code, it is not good!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

default case is not necessary but you should always have it and log/throw exceotion. In case of some error or problem with the value passed you will know right away the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you add it to the `default` clause, the last line

```
throw new YException();
```

will be *dead code*.

Note that in no case, the code will reach the last line. If `e` meets the cases `A,B or C`, it will reach a `return` statement, so it will exit the function. And if none of this cases are met, the `throw` in the `default` will be reached.

**In conclusion:** you should add it to the `default` clause (it's a good practise to always include a `default`) and delete the last `throw` line.

Comment: It won't because that also deals with the e == null case.

Comment: You are right, but I don't think you'd like to throw the *same exception* since those are different issues.

Comment: Assume that I do. Maybe in most cases I won't in which case this is an irrelevant question. But maybe there are some in which I might actually want to perform the same operations (throw an exception or what else).

Comment: Then you could throw that exception outside, but since the `default` is always recommended, you should add it and put a log/other operations you'd like to do when no cases are met (maybe because `e` have a invalid state). Definitely, I would throw a different exception.

Answer (score 0):

if in combination with switch for the same variable does not make sense to me.
It can work, but it is asking for trouble. 
Why not put the exception as a default action? Than you do not need duplicated code at all.